# Set Theory: Finding Unions and Intersections of More than Two Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having some trouble with this question. Any help is appreciated.

Let $V_i=\{\in \mathbb{R}|-\frac{1}{i} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{i}\} = [-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}]$ for each positive integer i.

Find:

$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{4} V_{i}$

Comment: Write out each of the four sets and take the union. Note that some are contained in others. If $A \subset B$ then $A \cup B = B$.

Comment: What is giving you trouble about this?  If we were to look at the case of only two sets instead of more, do you know what $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]\cup [-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}]$ will be?

Answer (score 2):

$[-\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{1}]\cup [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]\cup[-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3}]\cup [-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}] = [-1,1]$

Just draw each interval on a number line and you can see the result.